# Lots of laptop issues?

Tags: laptop, overheating

I got my mom's old Gateway NV52, model MS2274. It had major problems, such as battery life, overheating, and performance. Eventually, to fix the heating and the battery, I decided to turn it into a desktop. I got it to turn on with only the motherboard and screen (with it plugged in so there's power), but it was getting very hot. Some time around there, I wiped the hard drive so I could reinstall Windows.

All that was several months ago. I'm now using the hard drive in my PS3, as it's original one was failing. I now don't have a hard drive for it (the laptop), so I started messing with it. It's ancient thermal paste was in bad condition, so I temporarily replaced it with toothpaste. I was only in the BIOS for a couple minutes when it shut itself off and rebooted... to a white screen. I think the integrated graphics must have overheated or something, as I can restart it by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete, but it still does the same thing. My question is, can I "reflow" it by putting it in the oven for a few minutes? I've heard that sometimes helps, and if so, then for how long and at what temperature?

Comment: Why not just clean it off with some alcohol and replace it with fresh paste?

Comment: I don't have any right now, and toothpaste is supposedly a good alternative if you're in a pinch. It only lasts for a couple hours, but it works better than nothing at all, so I chose the "why not" route. We have a new laptop now, but considering the old one's specs, I think its more powerful, which is why I wanted to fix it in the first place.